# how to use lookups

Tags: oracle

Lookup table:-

```
FROM_METER  TO_METER    COST
1             5         0.004
6             10        0.006
11            20        0.012
```

Needed output:-  (here for 15 and 7 for example cost output will come as from lookup master)

```
METER  COST
15     0.012
7      0.006 
etc....
```

Answer (score 2):

A lookup table is normally used t provide code or reference values for regular data.  Assuming your business table is the one you called MASTER you would join its records to your lookup like this:

```
select m.meter
       , l.cost
from master m
      join lookup l
            on ( m.meter between l.meter_from and l.meter_to)
```

---

Your data model ppears to have a problem: it doesn't guarantee that every METER in the MASTER table will find a matching record in the lookup table.  This is why a more common approach is to use types or categories (say 'cheap', 'reasonable', 'expensive').

Obviously, without knowing your business rukes it is hard for me to say whether you model is correct, but you probably should consider what to do if the MASTER table doesn't have a matching row.  Perhaps the relation is enforced in the application but in my experience that approach is hard to make it bulletproof.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ? Meter, cost from Lookup 
where ? > = FROM_METER  
and  ? < = TO_METER
```

replace the `?` with your parameter.

Comment: @Ben - you're right. The reason I don't like using `between` is that lot's of people are getting confused about the fact that it's inclusive, and I like my code to be simple and obvious ;)